Does __shfl_sync in CUDA always operate on registers, or does it involve shared memory or global memory in some certain situations?
This question is inspired by the discussion in this link: When is shfl.sync.idx fast?, where it was debated whether __shfl_sync() and other warp-level shuffle instructions operate directly on the register file in addition to the original question "When is shfl.sync.idx fast?".
From my understanding, variables in kernel functions are allocated to registers or memory (global/shared) based on compiler optimizations, and developers cannot explicitly force variables to reside in registers.
This raises two related questions:

Is it guaranteed that variables used in __shfl_sync() or other warp-level shuffle instructions are stored in registers and not in shared or global memory? If so, what ensures this?
If there is no such guarantee, how can we explain why __shfl_sync() is consistently faster than exchanging data through shared or global memory? Does this imply that register-level operations are not strictly required for its performance advantage?

Here’s an example for context:
__global__ void shuffle_example(float *output) {
    float val = threadIdx.x; // Thread-specific value
    float shuffled = __shfl_sync(0xFFFFFFFF, val, 0); // Get value from lane 0
    output[threadIdx.x] = shuffled;
}


How can we ensure that val is in a register during the shuffle?

Even if you cannot ensure it, the compiler can put it in a register. That is, why it is fast. The alternative would be local memory (special kind of global memory). Shared memory is nearly as fast as shuffle (50%).

The input of these has to be a register, i.e. if the data is shared or local memory it will be loaded first. How the operation itself is implemented is a proprietary implementation detail that could differ between GPU architectures.

An interesting detail is that when one hovers over the "Other" field of the shared memory table in the "Memory Workload Analysis" of Nsight Compute, it says: "Shared memory traffic generated by other instructions, including S2R, SHFL and fully predicated-off shared memory accesses" (emphasis mine), i.e. shared memory might be involved at least in some architectures, but maybe that is just emulation when the actual shuffle isn't available.

No one says that shuffles are consistently faster than shared memory. See e.g. Why is __shfl slower than shared memory (Nvidia Developer Forums). Especially when overused, shuffles can be a bottleneck in my experience, probably explained by its low throughput.

@paleonix I think shuffle uses the same pipepline (MIO) and the same ports and crossbar as shared memory.

Shuffle is faster, if the alternative is storing and reading. If it is just a read, you do not gain much, if at all.

@Sebastian Yeah, I guess the actual problem in that old forum post is that the shuffles need to wait for the shared load while the three shared loads are independent and can be pipelined. I.e. it is about (combined) latency instead of throughput.

@Sebastian And I think another performance trap is that e.g. in an unrolled loop they will prevent reordering of instructions even if enough registers are available for additional pipelining (same as other synchronization primitives needed for communication through shared memory).

shuffle ops operate on registers. It does not involve data in shared memory or global memory.  The code you write may of course include shared or global, but the actual operands to the shuffle ops will always be presented in registers. Discussions about register usage IMO are not best facilitated by studying either C++ source (which has essentially no concept of registers) or PTX (whose definition of registers differs from the actual hardware, since PTX refers to a virtual architecture).  At the SASS level, a shuffle instruction operates on registers.  The GPU is largely a load-store machine.

__shfl_* and its improved version __shfl_*_sync always operate on registers. They have to, because their very premise is to be a faster alternative to shuffling data using shared memory.
They have been a part of CUDA since version 5 (version 9 (I think) for the sync versions) and have always operated the same.
The shuffle instructions share data between threads in the same warp if the source is known (a gather operation). This is often used to communicate a single value to all threads, or to perform reduce operations -- although on newer hardware reductions can be more efficiently done using atomic operations on shared memory, (or from Ampere onwards) using the __reduce_*_sync instructions.
On every incarnation of NVidia hardware that supports shfl (Kepler or newer), it is implemented in SASS as a SHFL instruction, with an added SYNC as needed.
This can be easy tested by selecting the SASS display on compiler explorer with a custom --arch=smXX command line, see: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/WYzcn83d1
If you vary the --arch setting, you'll see the exact same SASS code for __shfl, even though the surrounding instruction mix may change.
__global__ void shfl(int* data) {
    const auto a = threadIdx.x;
    data[threadIdx.x] = __shfl_down_sync(-1u, a, 1);
}

compilation:



architecture
SASS




sm52
SHFL.DOWN PT, R0, R4, 0x1, 0x1f


sm60
SHFL.DOWN PT, R0, R4, 0x1, 0x1f


sm70
SHFL.DOWN PT, R5, R0, 0x1, 0x1f


sm80
SHFL.DOWN PT, R5, R0, 0x1, 0x1f


sm90
SHFL.DOWN PT, R5, R7, 0x1, 0x1f



Unfortunately, compiler explorer only supports downgrading CUDA down to version 9.0, so I cannot show you the SASS output before Pascal, but I know from memory that all they way back to CUDA 5/Kepler, the output is in fact the same.
When is shfl faster than shared or global memory
The problem with shfl is that it has latency, if you do, say, a reduction, you can do this like so:
const auto a = threadIdx.x;
auto sum = a;
sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 1);
sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 2);
sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 4);
sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 8);
sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 16);

These instructions form a dependency chain where every instruction needs to wait for the result of the previous instruction.
If you code it like so:
const auto a = threadIdx.x;
auto sum = a;
__shared__ int result;
result = 0;
atomicAdd(&result, a);

It will run faster on newer hardware, I forget how much, but faster.
This is because atomic operations on shared memory have been optimized a lot on newer hardware, and shfl has not.
If you have Ampere or newer, the __reduce__add_sync will do the reduction faster still.
Global memory and the L2 cache are both so slow that they are never faster than shfl.
On modern hardware the guideline is that shfl will be faster if you can save a write + read from shared memory, but a single read from shared mem will be faster than shfl.
A single atomicAdd will beat a stack of 5 shfl's to do a reduction.
So shfl has its uses, but it is no longer the catch-all tool is was back in the Pascal days.
Spilling of registers to the stack
In CUDA the stack is backed by local memory, which is really global (sigh) memory backed by the L1/L2 cache.
Unlike on the CPU, on NVidia GPUs the stack is slow.
The way the stack works is that the GPU will do a LDL/STL (load from /store local memory) and then use the registers.
The GPU is best viewed as a RISC processor, so it does not have x86-like instructions that can operate directly on main memory. Every non-load, non-atomic instruction always operates on registers only (with some exceptions for constant memory).
Stop looking at PTX
PTX is a byte-code, like the Java JVM. It has a bunch of simplifying abstractions that the underlying GPU-hardware does not have, it also misses a pass of the excellent NVidia optimizer. It is somewhat like looking at -O0 Intel x86 assembly, that's not the code your GPU actually executes.

Good answer, a small additions: most instructions can directly use constant memory (indexed read-only memory with same runtime index in each thread of the warp for full performance) in addition to non-uniform and uniform registers (uniform registers have the same data for each thread of the warp).

@Sebastian At least judging from compiler output things have become more RISCy on recent architectures as local memory loads are done explicitly I think.

@paleonix Could local memory reads be used directly in early architectures? Are you sure?

@Sebastian Sorry, I meant constant not local.
